# Suggest while typing email

Tags: android, autocomplete, autosuggest

I want to suggest user while he is typing his email.

Like,  a user's email is **user@domain.com**

while he will start typing '**u**' I want to suggest **u@domain.com**, **u@yahoo.com** and something more.
Same as  for **us**, **use** or **user**.

I tried with http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html.
But it seems, suggestion is available while word is matched.

What to do now?

Comment: create your own custom list for all suggestions.

Comment: I did that. But can't make for all time suggestion.